# Powershell. How to join two separately consecutive strings in one string in file?

Tags: powershell

I have a file. I need to select some consecutive strings, join them and put them in the file on place first of selected strings in powershell script

I try:

```
$test=cat $file |select-string -pattern '<DIV>$' -Context 0,1|%{$_ -split "\r\n"}
$t= -join ($test[0],$test[1])
cat  $file|%{$_ -replace '$test','$t'} > temp.txt
```

or this

```
cat $file | %{$_ -replace '<DIV>[\u000d\u000a]{0,2}',""}>temp.txt
```

but fail

Comment: Please post sample input data from the file to show what your are searching for.

Answer (score 0):

From what you show as code, I conclude you want to remove line feeds after a div tag.

cat, as an alias of get-content returns an array, so line feeds are reset by array output to file.
There are certainly strict powershel cmdlets ways of doing it.

The fastest I found is:

```
[io.file]::readAllText("$file") -replace "<DIV>`r`n" "<DIV>" > temp.txt
```

`readAlltext` keeps the line feeds of the file, so the replace works.

HTH